# Invalid application class path in Google StackDriver Debugger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-debugger

I am using Google Stackdriver Debugger for my application. My JVM argument for including the agent looks like this :

```
JAVA_OPTS=-agentpath:/opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent.so=--cdbg_extra_class_path=/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classfiles
            \ -Dcom.google.cdbg.module=app_name
            \ -Dcom.google.cdbg.version=app_version 
            \ -Dcom.google.cdbg.auth.serviceaccount.enable=true
            \ -Dcom.google.cdbg.auth.serviceaccount.jsonfile=/opt/cdbg/gcp-svc.json"
```

But it doesn't work and the log files show the error : `E0219 18:52:12.505424 31772 jni_logger.cc:61] Invalid application class path`.

I have another "`classpath`" (`/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp/classfiles`) which only has an XML file named `logback.xml` and is the supposed path according to the documentation, but I am not sure if it is correct. I followed this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-java#extra-classpath) to set that variable.

[This](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-java/blob/387a904d58260637c2433c2191395fd3d93cd765/src/agent/internals/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/cdbg/debuglets/java/ResourceIndexer.java#L155) is the source code of the debugger where it specifies the condition for raising an exception.

What is the classpath supposed to be? I also tried specifying a directory which included all the `*.jar` files but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Looking at (https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/java#web_servers) and the Git link, your configuration files seem up to spec minus one thing that I can’t quite understand. Could be nothing but the current classpath seems to have directory redacted from what you have set in your extra_class_path= . If you change this to have identical  directory names, does it still give you an invalid application class path error?

Comment: May I know what you mean by *identical directory names*? @AshikMahbub

Comment: I just re-read my message. Sorry for the fuzzy language used there. Did you have any progress with this issue since it was posted?

 Just wanted to clarify my comment.

Your JVM argument has --
JAVA_OPTS=-[...]=--cdbg_extra_class_path=/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classfiles

And where your classpath is 
/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp/classfiles

missing  /WEB-INF/

Is that intentional?

Second, the GIT doc lists 

-agentpath:/opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent.so=--cdbg_extra_class_path=/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes

And you have your myapp/classfiles [instead of classes]